# How are LINQ methods attached to non-generic arrays?

Tags: linq

Let's say I declare this string array:

```
string[] arr = new string[]{"foo", "bar"};
```

How is that the LINQ extension methods are being attached to it?

I know the LINQ extension methods are declared in System.Linq.Enumerable, but the extension methods act upon `IEnumerable<TSource>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

Since arr isn't a generic, and to my knowledge doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>` how is the `Where()` extension method attached to it?

Comment: A `String[]` is `IEnumerable<String>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx):

> Starting with the .NET Framework 2.0, the `Array` class implements the `System.Collections.Generic.IList<T>`, `System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>`, and `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` generic interfaces. **The implementations are provided to arrays at run time, and therefore are not visible to the documentation build tools. As a result, the generic interfaces do not appear in the declaration syntax for the `Array` class, and there are no reference topics for interface members that are accessible only by casting an array to the generic interface type (explicit interface implementations)**. The key thing to be aware of when you cast an array to one of these interfaces is that members which add, insert, or remove elements throw `NotSupportedException`.

Therefore, since `T[]` *does* implement `IEnumerable<T>`, and the *compiler* is fully aware of that fact, it is perfectly legal to use extensions methods defined on `IEnumerable<T>`s on arrays.

Comment: Aha! Mystery solved! I didn't realize how things had changed with T[] between .Net v1.0 and v2.0, thanks for the info. It's been bugging me for a while :)